# Is half a Euro cylinder lock practical in a patio door?

Tags: doors

If you have a sliding patio door with a Euro cylinder lock in it, it probably opens from both sides. If you only wanted opening from the INSIDE, could you replace the cylinder with a half cylinder and blank off the outside hole? I'm thinking of this from a security perspective, so that there is no outside cylinder that might be attacked.

Realistically, the door can't be opened from the outside  due to other locks anyway.

Comment: If you're only opening from the inside, why a lock at all?  You want a simple dead-bolt actuator, since without a key there's no reason for a cylinder.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft Err, what's a dead-bolt actuator?  Is it electric?

Comment: No, just a simple lever or knob as on a typical keyed deadbolt.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft Carl, it's a sliding door so I'm not sure how that could work.